# How to use a TypeScript cast with JSX/TSX

Tags: typescript, reactjs

When casting in a `.tsx` file, the compiler assumes it to be JSX, e.g.:

```
(<HtmlInputElement> event.target).value
```

gives an error

> JSX element type 'HtmlInputElement' is not a constructor function for JSX elements

How do you cast TypeScript in a `.tsx` file?

Comment: `as` is the recommended syntax for type assertions. I mention this here as well https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html 

Comment: This would explain the 100+ errors that resulted in my IDE just from switching the .ts extension to .tsx   when porting typescript code into React.   There was one <typecast> early on in the file and everything else thereafter was misinterpreted.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The `as` operator was introduced to TypeScript 1.6 to replace casts in `.tsx` files, e.g.:

```
(event.target as HTMLInputElement).value
```

The TypeScript wiki explains the 1.6 changes:
[it makes the new `as` operator the default way to cast (removing any ambiguity between JSX expressions and the TypeScript prefix cast operator)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new-tsx-file-extension-and-as-operator)