# How to get enum key by value in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an enum like this:

```
export enum Colors {
    RED = "RED COLOR",
    BLUE = "BLUE COLOR",
    GREEN = "GREEN COLOR"
}
```

Could you let me know how to get enum key by value please? i.e., I need to pass "BLUE COLOR" and get 'BLUE'.

`Colors["BLUE COLOR"]` gives error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"BLUE COLOR"' can't be used to index type 'typeof Colors'. Property 'BLUE COLOR' does not exist on type 'typeof Colors'.`

Comment: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/typescript/angular+print+enum+value

Comment: This answer was the most helpful for me (getEnumKeyByEnumValue): https://stackoverflow.com/a/73681064/470749

Answer (score 78, accepted):

If you want to get your enum key by value in that case you have to rewrite your enum in following manners: But same format also might be work in older version as well.

***For Vanilla Js it should be like below:***

```
 enum Colors {
    RED = "RED COLOR",
    BLUE = "BLUE COLOR",
    GREEN = "GREEN COLOR"
}
```

***For .tsx it should be like below:***

```
 enum Colors {
        RED = "RED COLOR" as any,
        BLUE = "BLUE COLOR" as any,
        GREEN = "GREEN COLOR" as any
    }
```

***For .ts it should be like below:***

```
enum Colors {
  RED = <any>"RED COLOR",
  BLUE = <any>"BLUE COLOR",
  GREEN = <any>"GREEN COLOR"
}
```

Then you can get like this way:

***Retrieve enum key by value:***

```
let enumKey = Colors["BLUE COLOR"];
    console.log(enumKey);
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Another way: Retrieve enum key by value:***

```
let enumKey = Object.keys(Colors)[Object.values(Colors).indexOf("BLUE COLOR")];

console.log(enumKey);
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Test on jsfiddle:***

[Coding sample on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/faridkiron/bwrg15e9/8/)

**Note:** There are new annoucement published on 25th August with TypeScript 4.8. Please be aware of it. [You could have a look here.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8/#unconstrained-generics-no-longer-assignable-to)

Comment: When I use <any> I get the following errors: ```Property 'any' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.ts(2339)
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'Colors'.ts(2322)
JSX element 'any' has no corresponding closing tag.```

Comment: May be you have taken your file as .jsx. It should .ts

Comment: It works but my react app throw these errors when I use <any>

Comment: My file extension is .tsx

Comment: Yes because react doesn't has any corresponding `data type` with `any` so replace that with `object` that should also work.

Comment: It considers ```<any>``` or ```<object>``` as ```Element``` and says ```Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'Colors'```

Comment: Thank you. It worked:
```export enum Colors {
  RED = "RED COLOR" as any,
  BLUE = "BLUE COLOR" as any,
  GREEN = "GREEN COLOR" as any
}```
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613981/how-to-use-a-typescript-cast-with-jsx-tsx

Comment: Updated the answer as I am also tried that and alternative too. Thanks

Comment: why does this answer work?  How does the `any` enable 'reverse lookups'?  Thanks

Comment: Getting error: `Computed values are not permitted in an enum with string valued members.`

Comment: Would you please check this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27976). Hope it would help you.

Comment: as Dedi has written above, this answer does not work anymore..

Comment: You could try either the way given. Additionally, are the context same? How do you trying? In above context its still working.

Comment: Be careful when using this with .tsx, it isn't mentioned here but this will have negative effects on inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your concern, but here is no issue on `inheritance` so there will be no further problem.

Comment: For TypeScript 4.8, you'll need to add a non-null assertion on the enum type to avoid a new error (see [Correctness Fixes and Breaking Changes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8/#unconstrained-generics-no-longer-assignable-to) section)

Comment: I'm aware of these changes announce on 25th  August however, I have answered this back in 2020. If you have better solution, you could offer that in another thread as you are always welcome therefore, added the reference.

Comment: This is awesome. I should've found this earlier..

Answer (score 54):

```
const findMe = Object.keys(Colors)[Object.values(Colors).indexOf("BLUE COLOR")];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anniebbird/agy3unfk/3/

Answer (score 27):

I am using this function

```
export function getEnumKeyByEnumValue(myEnum: any, enumValue: number | string): string {
  let keys = Object.keys(myEnum).filter((x) => myEnum[x] == enumValue);
  return keys.length > 0 ? keys[0] : '';
}
```

Tests with jest

```
describe('enum', () => {
  enum TestEnumWithNumber {
    ZERO
  }

  enum TestEnumWithString {
    ZERO = 'ZERO'
  }

  it('should return correct key when enum has number values', function() {
    const key = getEnumKeyByEnumValue(TestEnumWithNumber, TestEnumWithNumber.ZERO);
    expect(key).toBe('ZERO');
  });

  it('should return correct key when enum has string values', function() {
    const key = getEnumKeyByEnumValue(TestEnumWithString, TestEnumWithString.ZERO);
    expect(key).toBe('ZERO');
  });

  it('should return correct key by passing corresponding string value', function() {
    const key = getEnumKeyByEnumValue(TestEnumWithString, 'ZERO');
    expect(key).toBe('ZERO');
  });
});
```

Hope it helps someone

Comment: I like this answer but is this function possible without using `any`?

Comment: @AaronHill I don't know what else would work apart from `any`

Comment: I'm a big fan of unit tests, however, your final unit test would be better if the KEY and VALUE were different. For example, change the value to the string '0' and keep the key as 'ZERO' to prove that passing the value in works in retrieving the key. As-is, your method could just be returning the value with 'ZERO' as the argument representing the key, and your test wouldn't prove otherwise.

Answer (score 18):

Improved *getEnumKeyByEnumValue* without using **any**:

```js
export function getEnumKeyByEnumValue<
  TEnumKey extends string,
  TEnumVal extends string | number
>(myEnum: { [key in TEnumKey]: TEnumVal }, enumValue: TEnumVal): string {
  const keys = (Object.keys(myEnum) as TEnumKey[]).filter(
    (x) => myEnum[x] === enumValue,
  );
  return keys.length > 0 ? keys[0] : '';
}
```

Answer (score 7):

try like this

```
enum Colors
{
   RED = "RED COLOR",
   BLUE = "BLUE COLOR",
   GREEN = "GREEN COLOR"
};   

 console.log(Object.keys(Colors)[Object.values(Colors).indexOf('BLUE COLOR' as unknown as Colors)]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Improved getEnumKeyByEnumValue by adding type checks:

```
enum Colors {
    RED = "RED COLOR",
    BLUE = "BLUE COLOR",
    GREEN = "GREEN COLOR"
}

type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

function getEnumKeyByEnumValue<R extends (string | number), T extends {[key: string] : R}>(myEnum: T, enumValue: ValueOf<T>): string {
  let keys = Object.keys(myEnum).filter((x) => myEnum[x] == enumValue);
  return keys.length > 0 ? keys[0] : '';
}



let enumKey = getEnumKeyByEnumValue(Colors, Colors.RED);

// next line will trigger: Argument of type '"OTHER COLOR"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueOf<typeof Colors>'.
//let enumKey = getEnumKeyByEnumValue(Colors, "OTHER COLOR");

console.log(enumKey);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2ry1u8qb/

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to fix the code a little:

```
return Object.keys(myEnum).find(x => myEnum[x] === enumValue);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It doesn't work for my enum with string values:
`TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof MyEnum'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof MyEnum'.
`

Comment: I agree with PatryMilewski, because x has an any type.  TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof MyEnum'.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this fetching the enum keys:

```
enum Colors {
    RED = "RED COLOR",
    BLUE = "BLUE COLOR",
    GREEN = "GREEN COLOR"
}

for (let item in Colors) { 
    if (Colors[item] === "BLUE COLOR") { 
        alert(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: But I guess its little costly and noisy too.

Comment: It depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else is sharing runtime solutions, but if you want a Typescript solution here it is:

```
enum EXAMPLE_ENUM {
    KEY_ONE = 'Value One',
    KEY_TWO = 'Value Two'
}

// Result:
// type ReverseEnum = {
//     readonly "Value One": "KEY_ONE";
//     readonly "Value Two": "KEY_TWO";
// }
type ReverseEnum = {[K in keyof typeof EXAMPLE_ENUM as typeof EXAMPLE_ENUM[K]]: K}

// Result:
// type EnumKeyFromValue = EXAMPLE_ENUM.KEY_ONE
type EnumKeyFromValue = typeof EXAMPLE_ENUM[ReverseEnum['Value One']]
```

First create a type that swaps the places of the enum's keys and values. (ReverseEnum)

By using `typeof` enum it allows you to do indexed access into the enum's keys as a string. Then you get the name of that key using the reversed enum type.

It works perfectly with autocomplete on the value string and everything.