# How can I set location.href on Typescript without getting errors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this code:

```js
  const assetsRedirection = (props: AssetsProps): null => {
    const query = queryString.parse(props.location.search);
    const url = query.url;    

    if (url) {
      window.location.href = url;
    }

    return null;
  };
```

And I am receiving this error:

```
Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

Which comes from this line `window.location.href = url;` exactly at `window.location.href`.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: [Type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)?

Comment: Hi, @jonrsharpe can you elaborate?

Comment: I've added a link to the docs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it worked. I did `window.location.href = url as string;`. If you place an answer I can give you a cool green check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because query string parameters are allowed to be arrays in the query string spec. You can check the typing of your `queryString.parse` method to see exactly what it returns. I'm guessing it takes the spec into account and also allows for arrays.

Assuming you control the query string and are sure that `url` will always be a string, you can just cast it:

```
const url = <string>query.url;
```

Update: Since this is jsx, it'll interpret the brackets as html, so you'll need to cast using `as`:

```
const url = query.url as string;
```

Comment: If I do `const url = <string>query.url;` I get `Property 'string' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.ts(2339)` and `JSX element 'string' has no corresponding closing tag.ts(17008)`

Comment: Ah, react is interpreting it as jsx. You'll need to cast using `as` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613981/how-to-use-a-typescript-cast-with-jsx-tsx

Answer (score 1):

You should check if url is an array or just a string. If it is an arry, you should select the correct one.

```
if (url instanceof Array) 
  url = url[0]
```

you will also have to change your decleration of url from `const url = query.url` to `let url = query.url`